# Auto complete for startable/stopable services?

Tags: 10.10, upstart

Before upstart it was easy to get proper autocomplete, e.g. I type `sudo /etc/init.d/rsys<tab>` and what I want to do and there I go.

Now I need (?) to write `sudo stop rsys<tab>` but it doesn't work; seems the bash doesn't know what services can be started/stopped at this point.

Is there an Ubuntu package or manual activation for that?

Comment: thanks for bringing this to our attention, I filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/672067) about this.   You can subscribe to it if you want to follow the progress on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `service` command has autocompletion, e.g.:

```
sudo service rsys<tab> stop
```

becomes:

```
sudo service rsyslog stop
```

Apparently nobody took the time to write autocompletion support for upstart yet...

---

**Update:** There is bash-completion for upstart now (I'm not sure it will be included in Ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10, but should go into Ubuntu 11.04, and you can find a solution for older versions [in the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/672067) too).

Comment: Confirmed there's no bash completion for upstart's start/stop/restart/status commands yet.. file a feature request here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart

Comment: I files this as [bug #672067](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/672067)